# How can i use the same angular2 app twice on a webpage

Tags: angular

i'm building an App in Angular2 and i have two problems:

First: How can i start the app twice on the webpage like (I'm on a PLAIN-HTML Page that loads the Angular App, i'm not in an Component):

```
<div id="myFirstApp" appEngine>Loading 1</div>

<div id="mySecondApp" appEngine>Loading 2</div>
```

The Apps are using the same selector (appEngine) to get started. But only one App is starting (the first).

Second: How can i get the ID of the div in my angular 2 app, or how can i get some special parameter to the app?

I hope you can help me.

Best Regards Hackbard

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while searching for how to bootstrap multiple app roots / instances of the same app. This can be accomplished by manually bootstrapping your root level component(s) in the NgModule ngDoBootstrap method.

*(Note that in Angular 5+ this method may no longer be required, see [this Angular PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15668))*

We first find all root elements we want to bootstrap and give them a unique ID. Then for each instance, hack the component factory selector with the new ID and trigger the bootstrap.

```
const entryComponents = [
  RootComponent,
];

@NgModule({
  entryComponents,
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    RootComponent,
  ],
})
export class MyModule {
  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    entryComponents.forEach((component: any) => {
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
      let selectorName;
      let elements;

      // if selector is a class
      if (factory.selector.startsWith('.')) {
        selectorName = factory.selector.replace(/^\./, '');
        elements = document.getElementsByClassName(selectorName);

      // else assume selector is an element
      } else {
        selectorName = factory.selector;
        elements = document.getElementsByTagName(selectorName);
      }

      // no elements found, early return
      if (elements.length === 0) {
        return;
      }

      // more than one root level componenet found, bootstrap unique instances
      if (elements.length > 1) {
        const originalSelector = factory.selector;

        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
          elements[i].id = selectorName + '_' + i;
          (<any>factory).factory.selector = '#' + elements[i].id;
          appRef.bootstrap(factory);
        }

        (<any>factory).factory.selector = originalSelector;

      // only a single root level component found, bootstrap as usual
      } else {
        appRef.bootstrap(factory);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now, assuming our RootComponent's selector was '.angular-micro-app' this will work as expected:

```
<body>
    <div class="angular-micro-app"></div>
    ...
    <div class="angular-micro-app"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just reuse your top level component?
Just create another top level component on top and have it's layout be something like this:

```
template: '<main></main><main></main>'
```

And if you want to feed them some kind of different data, just add an `@Input` field, and then feed it into the template:

```
template: '<main [someData]="something"></main><main [someData]="somethingElse"></main>'
```

Having the same app run twice, with two bootstraps is really not a good idea. Better to stay within the framework.

Comment: I'm not in an Angular Template. i'm in the HTML Site that will start the Angular.

Comment: And I'm telling you it's not a great idea!

Comment: I know that but i can do that or switch to the old Angular Version ...
Or you have a better idea for buildung a quiz engine that can be multiple times on one page with different questions?

Comment: That's what my answer was meant for, convert your Plain-Html file to an angular component and include the quiz component twice :)

Comment: Yes ... but i have a CMS System ;) Where normal user build a quiz and add it to a site. i can not rewrite the CMS to Angular ;)